# What does "with little margin" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean Amazon has difficulty in making money? I used this link: 
http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/447102473

"**On the other hand, Amazon is becoming a revenue machine with very little margin**, while Facebook generates 5x more profit despite far smaller top line numbers."

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/heres-how-the-top-5-tech-giants-make-their-billions-2017-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Margin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_margin)* is a technical term from accounting.

> Gross margin is the difference between [revenue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenue) and [cost of goods sold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_goods_sold) divided by revenue, expressed as a percentage.

Basically, a lot of money flows through Amazon, from buyer to manufacturer, but Amazon gets to keep very little of it.